# Jquery script not working for form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

Form submit function is not working when written in an external jquery file, but works on the browser console. I have tried to debug a lot but couldn't find any error. Similar form submit functions written in the same jquery file work well but no idea why this one doesn't work.

Other such queries on stack overflow indicate that there shouldn't be any other element in the file with classname `submit` but I've checked everything and it's not this case. Would really appreciate any help.

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>

<form id="customStocksForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputMoney">Enter some money</label>
        <input type="number" name="money" class="form-control" id="inputMoney" aria-describedby="moneyHelp" min="1000" value="1000"></input>
        <small id="moneyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Minimum amount is 1000 INR</small>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <% data.map((asset, id) => { %>
            <% if(id%4 === 0) { %>
                </div>
                <div class="row bg-dark text-light">
            <% } %>
                <div class="col m-4">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="stocks" value="<%= asset %>" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck<%= id %>">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck<%= id %>"><%= asset %></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg justify-content-center my-5 px-4">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

This is the footer.ejs

```
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // some other form submit functions which work fine

    $('#customStocksForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Submitted');
    )};
)};
```

Comment: The closing div inside footer.ejs is a container div with the starting element in header.ejs

Comment: add button type as submit inside the form and give a try

Comment: That didn't work and it won't be the problem because button inside a form by default triggers a submit action.